# Saying "bye" to the boss when leaving office

Tags: behavior

I'm 22 years old and I got my first job a couple months ago, the workplace is very informal, even with bosses, we have coffee breaks together, we discuss and joke about things that come up at the time, but sometimes I find myself in an awkward situation.

When we leave the office we usually say "bye" to everybody in the other offices if doors are open. We have 3 offices of 5 people each and one office each for the boss and his brother which is the co-boss.

Sometimes it happens that the boss' door is open so I say "bye" without thinking too much and then I see he's on the phone, so I feel a little awkward and walk through.

How shall I act? Maybe looking inside first and only say "bye" if he's not on the phone? What shall I do if he's on the phone instead, like some gesture or some sort of smile?

Comment: What's wrong with simply nodding your head as you walk by if he happens to notice you? I'm not sure if this is really a workplace-specific question.

Comment: "I say hi without thinking too much and then I see he's on the phone" - Greet in a way that does not interrupt (hand gesture; non-imposing "good morning", etc.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong, that's what I'm doing currently since it came natural to me to do so, I asked simply because maybe I was missing something since that's my first work experience! :)

Comment: Usually when you are about to depart from a place you would say something like "goodbye" or "see you tomorrow". Saying "hi" would seem a lot more applicable to the encounter for when you first arrive.

Comment: Kind of inline with my previous comment, the title of this question should be "Bid farewell to the boss when leaving the office".

Comment: I'm italian, so translation may not be the best, sometimes we say "good morning" to the boss, but sometimes we just use the equivalent for "hello", it really is very random. Same for the evening, I usually say "hi, see you tomorrow" or "hi, have a nice evening", but in a really informal way.

@MichaelKaras, as you may understand english is not my first language so it's kinda awkward to find the right translation for this particular situation :)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Forgive my poor grasp of Italian, but are you by any chance referring to `ciao`?  If so, then the proper translation to English depends on how you are using it; we generally understand the word to mean *either* "hello/hi/greetings", or "goodbye/bye", depending on whether you (or the other person) is coming or going.  It does sound like "bye" would be a better translation than "hi" in the context you're using.

Comment: This is probably the most casual workplace issue I've ever seen on this board, and it makes me happy :)

Comment: You got the point, the meaning of `ciao` (which is what we say to each other most of the time) is `hi` in the morning when you first see the other person, and `bye` when you last see that person that particular day.

Comment: if he's on the phone a head nod (bro nod) works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm with @JoeStrazzere, a goodbye wave is probably best

Comment: @gardenhead Funnily enough, this is kind the _norm_ for a few countries over the world, mine included (Brazil, in this case). Most people around here _hate_ to be called Sir, for example!

Comment: @GiLA3 Why don't you ask him?

Comment: I have the feeling you might overthink this a little. Just say "bye" when walking by. If he's on the phone he may just wave back to you or ignore you. No problem here. A tiny "bye" is hardly a distraction :)

Comment: yep if you walk past and make eye contact and he's on the phone just wave as you go past.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If it is just a casual 'hi' that doesn't require a response, I wouldn't worry about it. A single word is unlikely to disrupt a phone call, and it's a polite and social thing to do. If in doubt, you could always fall back on voiceless gestures of greeting instead (a.k.a. a quick wave).

Comment: I think that's the confirm I was looking for, I usually say "ciao, buona serata" which translates to "hi, have a nice evening", but if I see him on phone I might just do a quick wave gesture

Comment: I disagree a little with this.   If I were on the phone and someone stuck their head into my office and said a single word to me when I'm not expecting it, it would interrupt my attention to whatever was on the phone and I would probably ask for whatever was said to be repeated because it would not have registered.   If you said a word and then disappeared, I would spend the rest of my phone call trying to figure out what you said and if it were important...maybe even who you were if it was very fast.   I would suggest a wave, or just pass by someone who is busy.

Comment: Totally agree, seems logical to me and that's what I've done until now

Comment: @bluegreen I agree, someone stuck his head in your office, said a word an left. You didn't register the word. Could have been "bye". Could have been "meeting". Coud have been "email". Could have been "fire".... Now there you are, wondering, checking your many email accounts and looking for flames with the corner of your eye...

Comment: @xDaizu he's doing the same thing at the same time every day. If it's 5.30 and he says a single word and disappears without waiting for a response, it going to be "goodbye".

Comment: @bluegreen, @ xDaizu In my experience you get used to a daily quick "hi"/"bye" very fast and can ignore it quite easily even when in a phone call. So is this a real problem for you or just hypothetical? Because the same argument _could_ also be made about someone sticking their head in saying nothing. Wouldn't you wonder who the person was and what they wanted? The only solution would be to not greet you at all then, since even a quick wave could be misinterpreted as any hand sign - maybe they signed to follow them or flipped you the bird?

Comment: @Kapep  Yes, I would wonder the same thing (maybe even more) if someone stuck their head in and didn't say anything...that's an odd thing to do.    Now...to be perfectly honest, I admit I get annoyed by 10 people greeting me and saying goodbye to me every day at work...I would just prefer they didn't do it...but people in my office do that too and I smile and nod or something.  My earlier comment still applies, I would be, and have been, distracted by people saying something while I'm on the phone, or just concentrating on something.

Answer (score 12):

Observe your seniors, is there a pattern there? You might wish to imitate them.

Ask your seniors. Use an informal setting, like a coffee break, to relay them this question. You will get answers tailored to your place rather than a best guess by some random Internet stranger like myself. And you improve your work image by showing that you care about fitting in.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll do that too :)

Comment: "You might wish to imitate them." - Except for the ugly tie. They only wear those because their children bought them as a Father's Day present.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have a more informal relationship developed so in your place I would do the following:
Door closed: absolutely no disturbing
Door is open: 
check inconspicuously if your boss is busy on some paperwork and or computer/on the phone/has clients or other employees with him, in which case you absolutely dont disturb him. If he doesnt seem busy or handling any task at the moment feel free to greet him.

Answer (score -2):

If I were your boss and you came to my office every day to tell me bye I would be very irritated and probably think something is wrong with you. Just the thought of someone telling me bye every time they left for the day is irritating me right now. Clearly you don't need permission to leave for the day so just go home. Say "bye" to the people working around you and leave.  Stop being a 'doofus' and just say "hi" and "bye" when appropriate. Don't make a special stop at the bosses office just to say bye. That's just weird. The fact that you're even questioning whether you're saying "bye" to someone is causing awkwardness should be enough of an answer already.